# Why can't I connect remotely to the MySql database on the server at GCP? Error etimedout

Tags: mysql, node.js

I am trying to set up a connection to my MySql database on Windows Server 2019 in Google cloud. I have the following script:

```js
    const mysql = require('mysql');

    const connection = mysql.createConnection({
        host: '3x.xx.xx.x6',
        port: '3306',
        user: 'auth0user',
        password: 'password123',
        database: 'mydb'
    });
    
    connection.connect(function(err) {
        if (!err) {
            console.log('connected')
        } else {
            console.log('not connected')
        }
    })
```

and when trying to connect it receives a timeout. Should I do some additional configuration on the server side to allow the connection?
I have created a user on the MySql side with whose credentials I want to connect to the database, but to no result.

```
> CREATE USER 'auth0user'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password'; 
> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'auth0user'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION;
> CREATE USER 'auth0user'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'auth0user'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;
> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

and:

```
> ALTER USER 'auth0user'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'password123';
> ALTER USER 'auth0user'@'%' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'password123';
```

I also added my IP to the inbound rule to allow connections.

Pinging works fine. However, trying the telnet command fails.

Comment: I would start by checking if the firewall is allowing remove connections through on 3306

Comment: maybe your server details for Mysql are not correct. try to connect in your server and check if it's working or not.

Comment: @RiggsFolly The problem occurs even when I completely disable the firewall.

Comment: @BhargavChudasama On the server everything works properly, I am connected to the server and everything works.

Comment: So there is any IP blocking access or not? maybe it's not allowed to access your IP

Comment: @BhargavChudasama I added the IP address of my local computer to the Windows firewall's outbound rule. From my local computer, the server is not reachable even with the telnet command. Ping works.

On the other hand, being on the server I am able to connect to the database as localhost on port 3306.

Comment: When I was talking about the firewall I was talking about the firewall on the remote server, not your local PC

Comment: @RiggsFolly Forgive the misunderstanding, but I also meant the firewall on the server.